# Access pixel along channels direction with OpenCV multichannel Mat

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a set of images with the same size and representing the same object but having some light differences. I want to study these differences pixel-wise using all images.
I'd like to stack them into a 3d array as a multi-channel Mat with many channels. We can say (x,y) the coordinates of a pixel inside every image, and (x,y,z) the coordinates of the (x,y) point for the z-th channel in the Mat.

I'm looking for a way to index the parallelepiped using the (x,y) coordinates in order to get the array of values in z direction.
In other words, I'm looking for a way to do:

```
Mat 3dMat; // previously initialized as a 3d stack of images
std::vector<byte> z_values = 3dMat.z_vec(x,y); // pseudo-code to explain what I'm trying to achieve
```

Any idea?
Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: Why not "vector<Mat> 3dMat;" and pushback the layers. Just be sure how to pushback and release data. Many questions around stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a datatype that has size/or numbers of channels your mat should have. Therefore you could use OpenCV types e.g.

```
Mat image(size,CV_8UC3);  // 3 -channel mat
cv::Point3_<uchar> val = image.at<cv::Point3_<uchar> >(row,column);
```

or you create your own :

```
struct MyType{ uchar x,y,z; };
MyType val = image.at<MyType>(row,column);
```

I don't think that you could use the vector type directly. You could use pointers but this seems not that what you want.